# Gson with polymorphism and collections

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, gson

After trying a long time to find a solution for my gson reading issue and after many changes I've done it comes to be the new hierarchy as following:

A extends X and implements a' and G.

B extends X and implements G.

C extends B

D extends B and implements d'.

--> the Collections:

A: List< B > collection

C: List< D > collection

By using Gson without registering any own adapters I can only get it probably write a json string for whole class A (including its collections). But reading misses something:

it reads A's properties well except the collection: for each item in its collection- the read produce items of type B (as the collection originally type, instead of the extensions types C and D)
so I assume I should write adapters for my classes, but don't really know to which of them..
(I think to C and D)
any help would be appreciate..

Comment: Do you want to change the JSON output for B and C from the default that Gson provides? If not, there's no need for these classes to have any `writeToJson()` method.

Comment: I'd argue that even A should not have that method because the class shouldn't care how it's represented in JSON -- that's usually the concern of some service layer handling requests.

Comment: If you're not happy with the default behavior of Gson for A, B or C, the proper way is indeed to write TypeAdapters. It's not too scary -- if you have a concrete use case, I'm happy to help.